# Account is unable to receive EOS

Tags: transactions, accounts

When trying to send to this account `jakejakejake`, it is not able to receive any EOS. 
When trying to send to it, it looks like the the transaction goes through (and it deducts from my account balance), but the transaction doesn't exist:
https://eospark.com/MainNet/tx/cc933f2a36769b388925724459306c1e7758e0a6df3c232d463a3422827ebfbc

And the `jakejakejake` account's balance does not update. Still zero.

Tried upping the RAM on that account. No change.

Has anyone else run into this?
Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: https://eosflare.io/account/jakejakejake shows your account fine.

Comment: Thanks @Kabir. Looks like it was related to RAM. It just took about 5-10 minutes after upping the RAM before the transactions started working

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a RAM issue. Account had 3.5k and needed >4k.

After bumping up the RAM it took about another 5-10 minutes before the account started working.